# .Net - using method extensions?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to use the method extensions to add methods that accept parameters ?

for example:

```
myString.NumberOfCharacters("a");
```

Comment: Like most methods in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes. like this

```
public static class StringExtensions
 {
    public static void NumberOfCharacters(this string someString, string param)
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

Check out the [MDSN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) of extension methods and the examples there.

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
public static int NumberOfCharacters(this string str, string extraParam) {

}
```